# What is this hanging concrete ledge underneath my mother's basement window?

Tags: basement, windows

This winter my mother had a pipe freeze in her basement -- we had to tear out some cabinetry that the previous owner built in front of the main shut off valve, and in doing so we decided to rework the entire utility room.

One of the (many) curious things we found, is that one of the windows appears to have a free hanging concrete ledge underneath it. There appears to be a piece of plywood underneath it, but the plywood doesn't appear required -- perhaps the plywood was part of the form used when pouring the window.

Does this seem like normal construction? Why would this be here? Is there any reason I couldn't just (with the appropriate tools) cut the concrete to be flush with the brickwork?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the dryer flexible duct is almost twice as long as it needs to be - shorten it so that there are no loops.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's the plan; we're just leaving it this long (for now) if we need to move the dryer temporarily.

Comment: Are you sure it is free hanging? It looks like it could have poured as a window sill.  those steel frame windows have been there a while and the plywood may have been part of the form for the sill as you mention.  Having concrete for a sill will last longer than wood.

Comment: Does the window open more? If opened all the way, will it rest on the concrete ledge? Is the window hinged in a way that involves the concrete ledge?